# Slide part of Table View Cell away using pan Movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table with custom cells from NIB file. Result should look like, that I'm gonna grab the cell and slide it off the screen. NOTE: Just part of the cell. Other part will stay. I'm having a problem with running the pan Movement on the cell. The NSlog logs the movement right, but I can't move with the cell. My cell.m looks like this:

```
#import "MIKETableViewCell.h"

static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"MIKETableViewCell";

@implementation MIKETableViewCell

@synthesize timeLabel = _timeLabel;
@synthesize priceLabel = _priceLabel;
@synthesize infoLabel = _infoLabel;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}


-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer)];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}


-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)panGestureRecognizer
{

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer)];
    NSLog(@"Panned!");

    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self];
    panGesture.view.center = CGPointMake(panGesture.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                     panGesture.view.center.y + translation.y);

}

@end
```

Thank You for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue may be that you're recreating `panGesture` inside the `-panGestureRecognizer` method. Because of this, the `panGesture` you're using inside the recognizer method isn't the same `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that's calling the method, so `[panGesture translationInView:self]` may not return the correct value. try this:

```
-(void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];

    //log the translation so you can see if it's working
    NSLog(@"Panned with translation point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(translation));

    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                 sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
}
```

This way, `sender` is the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` calling the method, instead of a new, empty one you're creating within the method.

To make this work, you'd also have to change the first line in your `-layoutSubviews` method to `UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer:)];`. Note that the only thing that's changed is the added colon in `@selector(panGestureRecognizer:)` This is because your selector method now has the parameter of `sender`.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much you're a champ! But there is a problem (of course). The movement is not smooth, I would say it's twice as fast and the result is that the view is jumping all over the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your code t move your view isn't right. A pan gesture recognizer gives you values that start at 0 from the point the user first touches, and increase continuously the further the user moves his/her finger from that point.

You either need to record the starting center point of your view and add the translation value to that starting point to calculate the new center point, or reset the translation value to zero each time you adjust your view's center.

If you don't do that you keep adding the previous movement amount plus any new movement amount to the center point with each change in the translation value. That causes the amount of change to be amplified like crazy.

Imagine the user taps at (100, 100), and then drags down and to the right from there. You get called with a translation of first (+5,+5), then (+10,+10), then (+15,+15), then (+20,+20), and so on, up to (+100,+100). This means the user drags the view 100 points to the right and 100 points down. However, you first added (5,5) to the center, then (10,10), then (15,15), etc. By the time the user's finger gets to (200,200), you've added many times more than the (+100, +100) change the user actually made to the center position.

In your code, you could fix it by adding one line:

-(void)panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender

```
{
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];

    //log the translation so you can see if it's working
    NSLog(@"Panned with translation point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(translation));

    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                 sender.view.center.y + translation.y);

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    //---below is the line you need to add to zero out the translation.---
    [sender setTranslation: CGPointZero inView: self];
    //-------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: Ahh, I get it, thank you very much for great answer, I understand it now! Thank You!